# Sencha Ext JS 5.1.0 catch image setSrc error event

Tags: extjs

I load an image in extjs 5.1.0 with setSrc("myUrl"). In case the Url of the image doesn't exist how can I catch the "unable to find url" event? (I take in the web browser: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 -Not Found" )

I want this because i have to stop the loading splash icon when the image failed to load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native class Ext.Img doesn't have a error event.

Create your own class and extend from Ext.Img. Then set the dom onerror handler on the imgEl with this you can handle the load error event. In the callback you can fire your own event or set an standard image or whatever you want.

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lm1

```
Ext.define("MyImage", {
    extend : "Ext.Img",

    onRender : function() {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);
        me.imgEl.dom.onerror = me.onImageLoadError;
    },

    onImageLoadError : function() {
        alert("Error loading image")
    },

    onDestroy : function() {
        var me = this;
        me.imgEl.dom.onerror = null;
        me.callParent(arguments);        
    }
});
```

Comment: if the solution is ok for you then please do a upvote or mark as resolved.